# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name available as request attribute, and I don't know why

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I'm getting an error: `Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'foo' available as request attribute` and I can't figure out why.  I know there are some questions regarding this already, and I have tried their solutions to no avail.

As far as the headers for the code I have (all actual variables have been replaced with metasyntactic variables):

In the JSP that doesn't work:

```
<form:form name="myForm"
class="form-horizontal form-row-seperated" action="#"
onsubmit="return isformSubmit();" method="post" 
modelAttribute="foo">
```

In the Java controller for said JSP:

```
@RequestMapping(value="bar", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Boolean baz(
    @ModelAttribute("foo") FOOBEAN fooBean,
// Ten @RequestParam strings have been omitted for brevity
 , HttpServletRequest qux) throws QUUXEXCEPTION {
```

`foo` does not show up anywhere else in the configurator page.

I know I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what exactly.  If I'm not giving enough context, please let me know.

UPDATE: Here's the FOOBEAN class.  I'm reusing metasyntactic variables here; they are **not** the same variables that were in the controller class.  Also, `FOOBEAN` and `Foo` are not related other than that `Foo` is a variable within `FOOBEAN`.

```
public class FOOBEAN {

     private String Foo;

     private String Bar;

     private String Baz;

     private String Qux;

     private String Quux;

     private String Corge;

     private String Grault;

     private String Garply;


     public String getFoo() {
        return Foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        Foo = foo;
    }

    public String getBar() {
        return Bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        Bar = bar;
    }

    public String getBaz() {
        return Baz;
    }

    public void setBaz(String baz) {
        Baz = baz;
    }

    public String getQux() {
        return Qux;
    }

    public void setQux(String qux) {
        Qux = qux;
    }

    public String getQuux() {
        return Quux;
    }

    public void setQuux(String quux) {
        Quux = quux;
    }

    public String getCorge() {
        return Corge;
    }

    public void setCorge(String corge) {
        Corge = corge;
    }

    public String getGrault() {
        return Grault;
    }

    public void setGrault(String grault) {
        Grault = grault;
    }

    public String getGarply() {
        return Garply;
    }

    public void setGarply(String garply) {
        Garply = garply;
    }

}
```

Comment: How is the FOOBEAN defined? Please share the definition as well.

Comment: @Ayman The definition has been added.

Comment: I'm having a bit of a hard time reading what you wrote; is there any way you could please format it as code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the BindingResult object as a parameter and initialise the model as follows:

```
@ModelAttribute("foo") 
public FOOBEAN getFoo(){ 
    return new FOOBEAN();
}

public @ResponseBody Boolean baz(@ModelAttribute("foo") FOOBEAN fooBean, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest qui) {
    // method body does here 
}
```

Note that the getFoo method must be called in the GET handler, i.e. the method you use to return the view name.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should add those first four lines before my original method in the controller?

Comment: Yes, you need to add an object "foo" to your model before the view is rendered.

Comment: Okay, I did that and I'm getting a duplicate-modifier error on line 2 of your code.  I tried putting a semicolon after line 1, but then Eclipse thought I was making an enum and gave me a syntax error.  Maybe there was a typo somewhere in your code?

Comment: What is on line 2 exactly?

Comment: `public Person getFoo(){ `

Comment: If you're referring to changing `Person` to `FOOBEAN`, I had already fixed that typo when I got the error.

Comment: In that case, then the method name must be used somewhere. Try to change the method name from getFoo() to initModel() or something else of your choosing.

Comment: What it looks like is, when you wrote:

`public @ModelAttribute("foo")
public FOOBEAN getFoo(){`

The duplicate modifier error was referring to the `public` modifier; putting in the following code instead worked:

`public @ModelAttribute("foo")
FOOBEAN getFoo(){`

I will still be accepting your answer because it definitely helped.